# Using yield with superagent returns request object instead of response

Tags: yield, superagent

According to SuperAgent docs: [SuperAgent docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)

```
var res = yield request
  .get('http://local')
  .auth('tobi', 'learnboost')
```

However, I'm finding that the var res isn't res, its req. Meaning I have only access to the request object, not the response object with the fetched data that is usually passed to the end() chainable, which is obviously what I need.

Anyone experience with this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question was [answered on GH](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/935), figured I'd paste it here as well for others.  The following worked great for me!

```
var res = yield Promise.resolve(request
.get('http://local')
.auth('tobi', 'learnboost'))
```

Comment: Agreed, thats' what I ended up doing as well, thanks